# Why didn't Krishna take part in Draupadi's Svayamvara?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna, draupadi, balarama

In the story of Svayamvara of Draupadi, all the kings and princes participated. We have a list of all the famous kings and princes who tried to tie the bow and shoot such as Shalya, Shishupala, Karna, Duryadhan, etc. Almost all of them failed to do so except for Karna (who was stopped and rejected by Draupadi for being a charioteer).
In the whole list, we don't get to see Krishna taking part in the competition nor his ender brother Rama, nor even all those famous warriors of the Yadu clan such as Satyaki, the Vrishis, etc. When all the Kshatriyas were taunted for not being able to complete the task they yet why did they not intervene? Weren't all the Kshatriyas free to participate there?

Comment: He wanted Pandavas to marry Draupadi right? If he won the svayamvara how would the Pandavas marry draupadi?

Comment: Maybe Draupadi considered him his 'Sakha' so it wasn't appropriate to become husband from friend. Also, he may have deliberately wanted Pandavas to marry Draupadi and even Drupad was keen on getting Arjun to marry his daughter so that wouldn't have been possible if Lord Krishna participated.

Comment: For Sri Krishna, there is nothing at all,  in all the three worlds which He ought to acquire/attain, which is left unaquired/unattained ..But it is not the case of other Kshatriya kings, who have so much of aspiration for gains..How far  would it be relevant to raise a question as to Why Sri Krishna may not wish to participate?
**naanavaaptamavaaptavyam(Gita 3.22)** could be answer .